# Android: sending string from EditText with JSON to PHP - encoding troubles

Tags: php, android, encoding, utf-8

I'm having troubles with encoding text from Android EditText when sending it with JSON to PHP script.

First in Android I get the text from EditText element.

```
String s = editText.getText().toString();
```

then I post it throught HttpURLConnection to PHP script

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setDoInput(true);

JSONObject jsonParam = new JSONObject().put("mystring", s);

DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
os.writeBytes(jsonParam.toString());
os.flush();
os.close();
```

then I parse the JSON in PHP script:

```
$data = json_decode(utf8_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);
```

Everything works fine, but when I try to send some text with diacritics it seems that nothing is send and var_dump($data) is null. Is there something wrong with the formating or what could be the problem?

Thanks for help.

**EDIT**

Elsunhoty answer works but I have to use urldecode() in PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to trim Your Text  First

```
   String s = editText.getText().toString();
         s  = s.trim();
```

and then Encode the Text

```
  String encodeText= "";
                try {
                     encodeText= URLEncoder.encode(s,"utf-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't work. It's not null anymore but the diacritics aren't correct.